# Multi Store view - product name for each store

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, multistore, catalog, localisation

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1

I have a store in English, I want to have the same store (same categories and products) just translated to Spanish.

I used this tutorial to achive this: [Ref.](http://sherodesigns.com/magento-tutorial-creating-multi-language-stores/)

I created another store view in my store. Under `System->Configuration->General->General->Locale Options->Locale` for the Spanish store view, I un-checked the "**Use Website**" and selected "**Spanish**".

Under `Catalog->Manage Categories` I changed the store view to **Spanish** and I translated the Name of each category to Spanish.

Under `Catalog->Manage` Products I changed the store view to Spanish and I translated the Name of each product to Spanish.

Now, In the frontend, when I switched the the Spanish store view (using the language switcher), I can see my store in Spanish, including the categories and products.

But when I add a product (that I can see in Spanish in the category page) to the shopping cart and goes to the shopping cart, I can see the product, but is name is in English (although I'm in the Spanish store view). Also under Order Review in the Checkout page it's in English.

What can be the problem?
How can I fix it?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I upgraded my store to 1.9.2.3 and it doesn't help.

Comment: Might be some problem with the theme you are using. Have you checked falling back to the base Magento theme ?

Comment: I changed the package for the Spanish store view to "default". The theme has changed, but the products name in the shopping cart is still in English.

Comment: Must be a problem with one of your extensions then, which changes how products are converted to quote items. Try to disable them one after each other using the files in `app/etc/modules` to find out which one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any module for checkout which is extending layout ?
There might be the scenario that any module is extending the product collection in cart and not reading based on selected store view.
Default Magento view will have localized attribute value only and as you say product name is in Spanish in all other pages then check your installed modules.